# How can I increase vertical split size in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

`<C-w>+` does not do anything. It works with horizontal splits though. What am I missing?

Edit: I have also tried `<C-w>>` and `:res +30` but these two things don't work either. There's no remap for these commands AFAIK and checked.

Comment: Hi @samuelnihoul is your problem solved? Do we need to enrich the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the width of the split you need to use <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`<` and <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`>`.

More information with: `:help wincmd` or `:help Window-resize`.

The following commands could also be of some help:

- `:vertical resize +10`

If you want to change the size of your split you could be interested to the [winresizer](https://github.com/simeji/winresizer) plugin.